# RunTimeException in UIAutomator Testing In Android

Tags: android, exception, android-uiautomator

Actually I am new to UIautomator testing. I have made a class which has to be tested. Can any one please tell me some steps how can I make my UIAutomator testcase class? I have got some errors like...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at 

android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4382)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase.<init>(UiAutomatorTestCase.java:5)
at com.example.automatorapp.test.Test2.<init>(Test2.java:11)
... 18 more
```

and my code is...

```
     package com.example.automatorapp.test;

    import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
    import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class Test2 extends UiAutomatorTestCase 
{

    public Test2()
    {
    super();
    }

    public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
    {

        getUiDevice().pressHome();

    }


}
```

plz some one help me??

Comment: The problem is on your constructor, `super()` can not be passed with null value.

Comment: but when i passed some values in constructor,it gives me error?

Comment: Just remove your constructor, you don't need it.

Comment: yaa i done with that also..but still it gives same problem..heyy do u know how to add javadoc in my case?

Comment: as i am unable to javadoc in my jar file?i search but i dont find javadoc?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you want exactly!

Comment: heyy actually i am unable to locate javadoc.Can u plz tell me where i can find javadoc,as in robotium we can easily download javadoc.ja file but in UIAutomator i am unable to find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nullpointer has already indicated, the constructor needs to be removed.

Here is the revised code (which I have compiled and successfully run)

```
package com.example.automatoapp.test;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;


public class Test2 extends UiAutomatorTestCase 
{
    public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
    {
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
    }
}
```

For the following, all the commands are run from the command line, not in an IDE

Here is how I compile & push the UIAutomator code to the device
`ant clean build && adb push bin/UIAutomatorExample.jar /data/local/tmp/`

And how I ran 'your' test
`adb shell uiautomator runtest UIAutomatorExample.jar -c com.example.automatoapp.test.Test2`

For completeness here is the output:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.example.automatoapp.test.Test2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
com.example.automatoapp.test.Test2:
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testDemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.example.automatoapp.test.Test2
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testDemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
Time: 1.535

OK (1 test)


INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
```